# Check for 2 classes jQuery html element

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have `tr:not(.discarded)` to check if a row has been class discarded. How can I check that a row doesn't have `discarded` or `bad` class? Should I use `tr:not(.discarded)` or `tr:not(.bad)` or something else?

Comment: The solution is in the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/): _"All selectors are accepted inside `:not()`, for example: `:not(div a)` and `:not(div,a)`"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:not` selector can take multiple CSS selectors as arguments.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) is a reference for this selector.

E.g.

```
$('tr:not(.discarded,.bad)')
```

Comment: @Andreas user hasn't provided much detail. i.e, what they are trying to achieve. In hindsight maybe you are right. I'll remove it now.